# Why do node.js promises not resolve even when put in then() block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I want to get the following workflow:

- Get URL of some images
- Pass those URL to another method to download them, and return the downloaded paths
- Use those paths to get the images and create a PDF file using [pdfkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit)

After a lot of tinkering, my code looks like this -

```
nightmare 
    .goto(url) 
    .wait('body') 
    .evaluate( ()=>document.querySelector('body').innerHTML) 
    .end() 
    .then((response) => { 
        return getJSONData(response);
    })
    .then((data) => {
        return processJSONData(data);
    })
    .then((pages) => {
        return createFile(pages);
    }) 
    .catch(err => { 
        console.log(err);  
    });
```

`getJSONData(data)` uses [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) to parse the HTML, and `processJSONData(data)` uses [image-downloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-downloader) to download the images. From my understanding, since this is a promise chain, it means the execution inside each then() will be asynchronous, but the then() blocks themselves will be executed sequentially. On running the code, I see that even though the first two then() blocks are executed sequentially (up to now), the `createFile(pages)` block is executed immediately thereby creating a corrupt PDF file. What could possibly be the reason behind this? How can I ensure that the `then()` blocks are executed synchronously, i.e. each `then()` runs only after the previous then is resolved?
The complete code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/E0A5hxsf).

Comment: your `processJSONData()` is doing async things, but does not wait for their results. You only wait for partial results within the `forEach()` but not for all of them to finish.

Comment: How can I wait for them to finish? Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're returning a promise from processJSONData

Comment: @badsyntax please have a look at the commented block in `processJSONData`. Even if I returned the `promises` variable, it returns immediately with a promise object and still creates a corrupt PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not wait for *all* async operations to finish within `processJSONData()`, but only for some parts of them.
Consider changing as follows:

```
function processJSONData(data){

    // map() instead of forEach() to get a promise per request
    const reqs = data.map(element => {
        // return the inner promise chain to be collected
        return download.image(element)
        .then( ({filename}) => {
            console.log("Saved to ",filename); 
            return filename;
        });
    });

    // return a promise that waits for all of them to be finished
    return Promise.all( reqs );

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sirko, this answer clears up a lot of doubt. I was returning `reqs` all this while instead of a `Promise.all(reqs)` which was the problem. Just one more question, though, could there be a possible explanation as to why sometimes the downloading hangs on a few particular images? And is there a way to force resolve it? I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65463384/) but even then the process does not end, and if the countdown is too small, ends immediately.

Comment: @srdg I have no immediate idea. My guess would be that you're overwhelming the server. Currently all your requests are sent at the same time, so maybe the server blocks you after a few images. Maybe consider something like [bottleneck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck) to run only a handful of requests in parallel.